# Time Series Plot Pandas Error

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataset like :

```
Date        Value
2017-11-08  6
2017-11-10  5
2017-11-16  3
2017-11-13  5
2017-11-06  6
2017-10-25  5
2017-10-31  1
2017-10-30  3
2017-10-13  6
2017-11-17  4
2017-10-22  2
```

i am trying to plot a simple line graph, using matplotlib

```
plt.plot(df['Date'],df['Value'])
```

it is showing a very weird graph: 
[image: Graph Image]

**how to do it the right way?**

**second question : how to get a range of dates and plot them ?**

my df.info()

```
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Date          272 non-null datetime64[ns]
Value         272 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.sort_values('Date').plot(x='Date', y='Value')
```

EDIT:

Filter by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Date'].between('2017-10-10','2017-10-31')]
print (df1)
         Date  Value
5  2017-10-25      5
6  2017-10-31      1
7  2017-10-30      3
8  2017-10-13      6
10 2017-10-22      2

df1.sort_values('Date').plot(x='Date', y='Value')
```

Comment: That is a fair suggestion !

Comment: how i use only a range of date? like only the data with dates of 2016-11-03 to 2016-22-04.